# Windows Server 2019: For system update patches tasks, Is there a difference between restart using command line "shutdown" and using GUI?

Tags: command-line, reboot, windows-server-2019

When a system patch is installed on Windows, there remain some tasks defered for "after restart" execution. When you restar from GUI there are some options to avoid "update tasks" on restarting, but when you explore cmd ´shutdown´ command help there are no options related to perform or avoid "update tasks".

My question is ¿When a Windows server is restarted by command line, those pending tasks are executed?

Comment: My experience with the shutdown command (although not with Server 2019) is that it will do updates.  Since your machine cannot update any other App while waiting for Windows Updates to complete, why not just do updates as most of us do.

Comment: Thanks @John for your comment. My intention isn't to avoid updates, I want to know if really theare are differences to take a decisicion about to program the restart (by script/ scheduled task) these restarts or to perform that restart connentic my terminal services and using the GUI to restart.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, restart by command and restart by GUI do the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10 there are no more differences between shutdown by GUI and
by the `shutdown` batch command.

You may still shutdown the computer without doing the updates from the
GUI, but doing the same from the command-line requires stopping the
Windows Update system service like this:

```
net stop wuauserv && shutdown /s /t 0 /f
```